# Fetch single value into Label from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, web-controls

I have a label called Label1. I am trying to pull a value from database using a procedure and assign to it. But this isn't working.

Proc result -

```
Mean_time
----------
528
```

Function which calls PROC

```
public DataSet getMeanTime()
    {
        DataSet dsMeanTime = new DataSet();
        dsMeanTime = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(sqlConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_getMeanWorkingTime");
        return dsMeanTime;
    }
```

Web control -

```
DataSet dsChartDetails = new DataSet();

helper hr = new helper();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GenerateChart();
}

private void GenerateChart()
{
    dsChartDetails = hr.getMeanTime();
    Label1.Text = WHAT TO WRITE HERE ;
}
```

If I try this

```
Label1.text = dsChartDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>(0).ToString();
```

I get this error -

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

My aim is to simply display the value from database using a label using procedure call.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but avoid using `sp_` for stored procedures.  This prefix is used to identify system stored procedures, which are handled slightly differently in terms of searching for them.  If you want a prefix, I might suggest `usp_` for "user stored procedure".

Comment: I'd say "sp_" is not an issue, but using a dataset to return single value is an overkill. Use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteDataset. It will be faster in terms of execution and easy in terms of coding.

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that the field is an `int`, so access it as an `int`:

```
dsChartDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<int>(0).ToString();
```

Wouldn't have made much sense to call `.ToString()` on a `string` anyway.

Comment: Strange I tried similar query before but didn't work.  This helped. Thanks !